# how to assemble a team for bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

This is a general question regarding the use of bitbucket (or other sites of its kind).  I'm wondering not so much how to create a team using the software, but more about how people assemble teams generally for online collaboration.  In my case I have a project that's probably 90+% finished but could use help with polishing the look-n-feel, a category of development I'm no expert in.  My question is - how do people locate appropriate team members online?  Is there anything like a collaboration team members hub where you can review people's skills and invite them to work on your project?   Or how do people advertise that they've put a project on bitbuckets.

Comment: hmmm...i think you could try out the stack overflow chatrooms?  This site is packed with experts :) :P